# Function to verify if product has stock enough in magento

Tags: function, magento, product

Is there a way to create a function to verify if the product has stock enough before the client add the product to the cart? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Magento checks the stock upon product adding by default. And show warning if there no items enough.  How exactly would you like to modify this behavior?

Comment: Actually this behavior does not work anymore, I would like to bring it back.

Comment: Please check the product stock management tab and make sure "Manage stock" is set to "Yes"

Comment: This is already yes to me.. okay, I discovered an other problem, there's an ajax pop-up that should appear before the message and it is not working correctly, maybe this can affect the message.

Comment: Ok, please share the solution once you have found it.

Comment: Amasty, I removed the pop up and the message is shown again. I'll correct this pop up to maintain it in my store, thank you for your attention.